# Jquery attr returns 0 instead of value

Tags: jquery

So i have a very simple html:

```
​<ul>
    <li value="test">test</li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And this jquery script

```
alert($("li").attr("value"));
```

It should return `test` but it returns 0, why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to return the text inside the li tag then:

```
alert($("li").text());​
```

You can't use the 'value' attribute(The 'value' attribute in the li tag can only be numeric). Rename it to data-value:

```
alert($("li").attr("data-value"));​
```

Comment: The 'value' attribute in the li tag can only be NUMERIC!

Comment: @kir -that is some valuable information! Do you have a reference for this limitation?

Comment: Ug... w3schools... :/ A much better source of info would be - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li.  But thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

Bassically your selector is capturing every `li` element you have. You might want to make your selector more specific. For the first `<li>` you could use -

```
$('li:first').attr('value');
```

Using an `id` attribute would be good too.

One more thing to note here is that you are trying to extract the value of the attribute called value and not the actual textual content within the element. If you want the attribute value then you are on the right track. If you want the content you might want to try using `text()` or `html()`.

If there are more than one elements that you want to process, you might want to think about using an `$.each` function.

```
var liValues = [];
$.each('li',function(index,value){
  liValues.push(value.attr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not working because `value` is simply not a valid attribute for an `li` element. As you can see for [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SvA8k/1/) changing the name of the attribute to `rel` makes your code work (although I don't think `rel` is valid either...strange).

You might want to consider storing this data in a different place. Perhaps using the `data-*` attributes.

```
​<ul>
    <li data-value="test">test</li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

alert($("li").data("value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fetching the value, the `value` attribute in the `li` tag can only be numeric.  Otherwise you will always get 0.
Instead of value you can use index. Like below:

```
.attr("value", function (currentValue, index) { return index } )
```

where

- `currentValue` is the value of the current element.
- `index` is the array index of the current element.